# переписать массив по закономерности

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дан массив let arr = [10,20,-8,4,-20,15,-6]; // нужно получить [-8,-20,-6,10,20,4,15]

выполнить сортировкой любой

главное такой же вывод, неважно каким методом нужно его реализовывать

альтернативный пример выполнения задачи

```js
let arr = [10, 20, -8, 4, -20, 15, -6];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] < 0) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}
for (let g = 0; g < arr.length; g++) {
  if (arr[g] > 0) {
    console.log(arr[g]);
  }
}
```

вывод: [-8,-20,-6,10,20,4,15]

Нужны любые решения задачи, главное чтобы результат соответствовал, есть ли ещё какие-то варианты помимо этого?

Comment: Нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" в вопросе. Разве это похоже на `[-8,-20,-6,10,20,4,15]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За один проход:

```js
const arr = [10, 20, -8, 4, -20, 15, -6];
const res = [];
let lastNegative = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] < 0? res.splice(lastNegative++, 0, arr[i]) : res.push(arr[i]);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [10, 20, -8, 4, -20, 15, -6];
let res = arr.filter(i => i < 0).concat(arr.filter(i => i >= 0));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133268/discussion-on-answer-by-igor----).